# Почему сессия обновляется при вводе пароля?

Tags: авторизация, php, сессия

До ввода пароля юзер выбирает свое имя, год, и т.д. из списка. Все это сохраняется в сессий. Но почему то сессия обновляется при вводе пароля и IP и т.д. теряется и возвращается "Вы заблокированы на время".

Первый файл

```
 <?
    //Устанавливаем время жизни кукисов в 30мин
    $min = 30;
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $min*60);
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', $min*60);

    session_start();

    //Проверка входящих данных на нежелательные данные
    //Защита от хакеров :)

function secureSuperGlobalGET(&$value, $key)
{
    $_GET[$key] = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_GET[$key]));
    $_GET[$key] = str_ireplace("script", "blocked", $_GET[$key]);
    $_GET[$key] = mysql_escape_string($_GET[$key]);
            if (strpos($key, "[") > 0)      $_GET[$key] = 0;
    return $_GET[$key];
}

function secureSuperGlobalPOST(&$value, $key)
{
    $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST[$key]));
    $_POST[$key] = str_ireplace("script", "blocked", $_POST[$key]);
    $_POST[$key] = mysql_escape_string($_POST[$key]);
            if (strpos($key, "[") > 0)      $_POST[$key] = 0;
    return $_POST[$key];
}
array_walk($_GET, 'secureSuperGlobalGET');
array_walk($_POST, 'secureSuperGlobalPOST');
```

Другой файл:

```
    $id_user = (integer) $_POST["id_user"];
    $password = (integer) $_POST["p"]; //да, да в паролях только цифры

    if(!$_SESSION["IP"])
    {
            $block_client = $_SESSION["BLOCK"];
            $ip = getVisitorIP(); //Взять ip клиента
            $_SESSION[$ip] = session_id();
            $_SESSION["IP"] = $ip;
    }

    //Обработка введенного пароля
    if ($id_user AND $password AND !$block_client AND (isset($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]) ) AND ($_SESSION[$ip]== session_id())) {

            $sql_password = mssql_fetch_row(mssql_query("SELECT USER.PASS FROM USER WHERE USER.ID_USER = '$id_user' "));

            if ($password == $sql_password[0]) {

                    $_SESSION["user_id"] = $id_user;

                    echo '{"redirect": "reports.html"}'; //https://stackoverflow.com/a/1534662
            } else {

                    if ($ip == $_SESSION["IP"]) {
                            $_SESSION["TIMES"] = $_SESSION["TIMES"] + 1;

                            if($_SESSION["TIMES"] == 10){ //Если не правильно ввели пароль 10раз
                                    $_SESSION["BLOCK"] = 1;   //то заблокируем клиент на сколько столько время жизни кукисов
                            }
                    }
                    JsonError("Не верный пароль");
            }
            exit;
    }
     elseif ($id_user AND !$password)
    {
             JsonError("Пароль не введен");
    }
     else
    {
            $_SESSION["BLOCK"] = 1;
            JsonError("Вы заблокированы на время");    
    }

?>
```

http://pastebin.com/JR87Zmxi

Comment: Ой, не до коментария, а до "array_walk($_POST, 'secureSuperGlobalPOST');" находятся в другом файле

Comment: Я разобрался) Надо было написать:
`$ip = getVisitorIP(); //Взять ip клиента
 if(!$_SESSION["IP"]){
  $block_client = $_SESSION["BLOCK"];
  $_SESSION["IP"] = $ip;
 }`

и

($_SESSION['IP'] == $ip)

Спасибо всем, кто помогал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверь условие:

```
if ($id_user AND $password AND !$block_client AND (isset($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]) ) AND ($_SESSION[$ip]== session_id()))
```

UPDATE:
Если $ip это адрес клиента то его нельзя использовать как ключ, тем более что в сессии адрес записан как

```
        $_SESSION["IP"] = $ip;
```

Comment: Тут "(isset($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]) )" лишние ковычки?

Comment: это нормально

Comment: вообще вся эта пляска вокруг ip непонятна, зачем вобще нужно делать такое `$_SESSION[$ip]=session_id();` очень смахивает на попытку дублировать, то что php само делать умеет.

Comment: Ну, вроде сессий берут ID из кукисов, не через IP.

Comment: да, но просто записать `$_SESSION['IP']=$ip;` и потом сравнивать:

   if ($_SESSION['IP']!=$ip) { /*....*/ }

 вполне хватит

Comment: ааа, а потом сравнить с IP, да?
$_SESSION['IP'] == $ip вместо этого ($_SESSION[$ip]== session_id())

Comment: Нет, не выходит(
Блин, больше не могу комментировать. Да бог с ним с IP. У меня при ввода пароля сессия обновляется, и вся инфа в ней теряется.

Comment: а что хочется то ? сравнивать надо **до** присваивания

Comment: сессион_старт в обработчике есть?